# Celery Flower show GMT time instead local timezone

Tags: django, celery, flower

I've installed Flower via pip, all work's fine, but when i see task time in flower it show me GMT time instead time in timezone.
[Flower task options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4hB7.png)

- **Pythnon - 3.4**
- **Django - 1.8.7**
- **Redis server v=2.8.17**
- **Celery - 3.1.19**

My celery and django conf:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

I've tried to change TIME_ZONE but it gives nothing, or set **CELERY_ENABLE_UTS = False**
If i change celery timezone properties - it's changed in workers log. HW time on server is 13:52 too.

In the worker log time is displayed correctly.

```
[2016-01-13 13:52:44,510: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: ***task[f652c89d-3f1b-4795-9e41-064ceb33b462]
[2016-01-13 13:52:45,529: INFO/MainProcess] Task ***task[f652c89d-3f1b-4795-9e41-064ceb33b462] succeeded in 1.0084812670002066s:
```

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786748/celery-scheduled-tasks-problems-with-timezone

Comment: What version of celery are you using?

Comment: I tried. As far as I understand - the time, in celery is determined by the time the problem is in displaying its flower.

Comment: Celery version 3.1.19

Comment: With the latest flower docker image `0.9.7`, the warning is gone and the logs are in the correct timezone. The app itself (in the browser) is not, though

Answer (score 1):

setting CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False, if your celery version is higher than 3.0 , so that keep same with celery beat and works well for all schedules.

`CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False`

setting CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'. so that flower time display well.

`CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'`

in Flask, settings should be push into conf obj by:

`celery.conf['CELERY_ENABLE_UTC'] = CELERY_ENABLE_UTC
celery.conf['CELERY_TIMEZONE'] = CELERY_TIMEZONE`

Answer (score 0):

**Settings.py**

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_TZ = True
```

**Worker+ BEAT**

```
celery -A APP_NAME worker --pool=prefork --concurrency=5 --autoscale=10,1 --beat -l info
```

**Flower With Redis broker**

```
celery -A APP_NAME --broker=redis://127.0.0.1:6379 flower --address=127.0.0.1 --port=5555
```

*Worker*
[image: Celery Worker task Screenshot]

*Flower*
[image: Flower Task Screenshot]