# Celery Flower shows UTC time zone in tasks tab instead local time

Tags: python, celery, flower

- celery==3.1.17
- flower==0.9.1
- amqp==1.4.6
- RabbitMQ 3.2.4

My flower runs under supervisor command:

```
flower --broker=amqp://login:passwd@x.x.x.x:5672/sb --broker api=http://login:password@x.x.x.x:15672/api/ --port=5599 --basic_auth=dev1:dev1ddd
```

The problem is that "tasks" tab in flower shows UTC time instead "Europe/Moscow" (as localtime). But in flower api (/api/workers) I can see, that celery settings are passed to flower: 
- "CELERY_TIMEZONE": "Europe/Moscow"

I have seen the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764812/celery-flower-show-gmt-time-instead-local-timezone?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but I have not any Flask. Can you please tell is there is ability to change time in "tasks" tab in flower from UTC to any other?
Regards

Comment: Do you Set `CELERY_ENABLE_UTC` to `False`?

Comment: Do check this document also in case you are dealing with celery beat [link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#time-zones)

Comment: Hello, yes, i have tried to set CELERY_ENABLE_UTC to False but nothing changes.

Comment: try to check timezone settigns with api [link](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) to check your configuration.

Comment: Thank you. As i noticed, in api/workers time zone is "Europe/Moscow" as i need, so now I have no idea why time zone in "flower/tasks" tab is still UTC